# Rails 3 + Sorting of Years in descending with days

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails, I am trying to create two dimensional but while searching a lot, I found most of the people suggest that in place of `Array, HASH` has to be used.

Here I am trying to build an array of years having descending orders, but I get this years randomly so I used array sort. Problem arises here, I want to pass one more value with the year like number of days with every year.

So while sorting, I will loose the related values present in another array.

Example :

```
   year = ["1990", "1995", "2010", "1985" ]
   days = [ '10', '20', '2', '50' ]
```

Now I am not able to sort days as per year descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off... you need to open a close hashes with curly braces:

```
{"1990" => '10', "1995" => '20', "2010" => '2', "1985" => '50'}
```

Basically, you're keying the year with the number of days associated with that year. To key, you use a hash rocket (`=>`) to denote the key and value.

Then, to sort in descending order of keys (in your your case, the year), you'd reverse sort in this manner:

```
hash = {"1990" => '10', "1995" => '20', "2010" => '2', "1985" => '50'}

sorted = Hash[hash.sort.reverse]
#=> {"2010"=>"2", "1995"=>"20", "1990"=>"10", "1985"=>"50"}
```

Finally, you can access the the number of days by year:

```
sorted["1995"] #=> "20"
sorted["1985"] #=> "50"
```

Or access each pair sequentially:

```
sorted.each do |k, v|
    puts "Year: ".k." has ".v"\n"
    puts "Now let's look at the previous year."
end
```

EDIT:

If you'd like to merge two arrays together into a hash of sequential key-value pairs, you can do the following:

```
years = ["1990", "1995", "2010", "1985"]
days = ['10', '20', '2', '50']

Hash[*years.zip(days).flatten]
#=> {"1990"=>"10", "1995"=>"20", "2010"=>"2", "1985"=>"50"}
```

Comment: I am struggling to merge two array into hash. I know this sort method.

Comment: Wish you had mentioned that in your question. I've updated my answer to demonstrate how to merge two arrays into a hash.

Comment: As per my requirement :
irb(main):> keys = ["1980", "1985", "1970"]

=> ["1980", "1985", "1970"]
irb(main):> values = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):> zipped = keys.zip(values)
=> [["1980", 1], ["1985", 2], ["1970", 3]]
irb(main):> zipped.sort{ |x,y| y <=> x }
=> [["1985", 2], ["1980", 1], ["1970", 3]]

Answer (score 0):

A good one liner would be as below :

*Ascending order:*

```
year = ["1990", "1995", "2010", "1985"]
days = [ '10', '20', '2', '50' ]

h = Hash[year.zip(days).sort]
#=> {"1985"=>"50", "1990"=>"10", "1995"=>"20", "2010"=>"2"}
```

*Descending order:*

```
year = ["1990", "1995", "2010", "1985"]
days = [ '10', '20', '2', '50' ]

p h = Hash[year.zip(days).sort.reverse]
#=> {"2010"=>"2", "1995"=>"20", "1990"=>"10", "1985"=>"50"}
```